# Could I automatically get a reference of arguments in a PHP function?

Tags: php, arrays, reference, arguments

Currently, I am reviewing websites written ten years ago. These websites uses the old MySQL API for PHP. PHP hasn't been upgraded since version 5.3, that's why I need to rewrite each database request from the old API to PDO.

The original coder has create for each table an object that wraps INSERT,SELECT and UPDATE requests.

On tables with a lot of rows, it is very painful to quote for each object each argument of each wrapped request, and there a dozen of sites that I must revise !

So, I think about a way to reduce the time spent on quoting each argument of the function by getting these in a loop and quote each of them in two lines of code in each function...

After viewing PHP manual, it seems that there is no way to get a reference of a function arguments. I can copy or count them, but can't get any reference.

Have you got any ideas or tips that will make this job sucks less ?

Here is an example of what I shouldn't do :

```
public function insert($titre, $tva, $intra, $remise = 0,
    $tx_remise = 0, $frais = 0, $code = 0, $nom = '', 
    $design = '', $adr = '', $cp = '', $ville = '',
    $tel = '', $fax = '', $rcs = '', $marq = '',
    $marq_g = '')
{
    $ville      = htmlspecialchars($ville);
    $design     = htmlspecialchars($design);
    $nom        = htmlspecialchars($nom);
    $adr        = htmlspecialchars($adr);
    $marq       = htmlspecialchars($marq);
    $marq_g     = htmlspecialchars($marq_g);

    $titre      = $this->db->quote($titre);
    $tva        = $this->db->quote($tva);
    $intra      = $this->db->quote($intra);
    $remise     = $this->db->quote($remise);
    $tx_remise  = $this->db->quote($tx_remise);
    $frais      = $this->db->quote($frais);
    $code       = $this->db->quote($code);
    $cp         = $this->db->quote($cp);
    $tel        = $this->db->quote($tel);
    $fax        = $this->db->quote($fax);
    $rcs        = $this->db->quote($rcs);
```

And what I approximately want to do :

```
    public function insert(...)
    {
        foreach($function->argumentsReference as $ref)
            $ref = quote($ref)
```

Of course **$function** isn't a real object, it is just a way to explain my idea with code.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `func_get_args()`?

Comment: func_get_args() returns an array of copied arguments, it is not what I really need because my arguments are reused later in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_defined_vars` to retrieve an associative array of all variables in scope, so as long as you use this at the top of your function then you'll effectively have a named copy of all the function arguments. Note that this is different to using `func_get_args`, which won't contain any default arguments if not provided in the call.

You can apply some logic to all the arguments (quoting, etc) using something like:

```
<?php
function foo($a, $b, $c) {
  foreach (get_defined_vars() as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value * 2;
  }

  echo implode(', ', [$a, $b, $c]);
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
// 2, 4, 6
```

Comment: Excellent solution, today I learned `get_defined_vars` is subject to scope.

Answer (score 0):

What about this (PHP 5.6 or higher required):

```
function insert(...$data){
   var_dump($data); // This returns an array of all passed arguments.

   array_map($data, function($datum){
       return htmlspecialchars($datum);
   }

   // Boom, now all entries in the $data array are "htmlspecialcharsified".

   list($titre, $tva, $intra, $remise, $tx_remise, $frais, $code, $nom, $design, $adr, $cp, $ville, $tel, $fax, $rcs, $marq, $marq_g) = $data;

   // As long as all parameters are passed in the correct order, you now have the desired variables available.

  // Do your magic here
}
```

Comment: It's not limited at all, because you can pass as much arguments as you would like. If you want to keep the arguments' names as an associative array (so that the order doesn't matter), you should indeed use `func_get_arguments()`.

Comment: Ok I understand much better. I'll keep that in mind for further needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you took PDO you need to use `PDO::prepare` and you get that rid of that problem.

Comment: You're right I think, but I wanted to follow the same request logic from the original code.

Comment: yes but why do you want to use pdo if you dont add more security ?

Comment: I am quoting each variable before passing them to MySQL. PDO::prepare() does more than just quoting ?

Comment: You can see The Hitchhiker's Guide to SQL Injection prevention https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#manual it cover in more detail what we are speaking :)